# Routing Error after changing model/controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

I just changed the name of my model `transaction` to `deed`, changed the controller names, helper names, ran the migration etc. etc.

Unfortunately I get the error:

**Routing Error**

```
Couldn't find TransactionsHelper, 
expected it to be defined in helpers/transactions_helper.rb
```

and

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

No remaining reference to `TransactionsHelper` `transaction(s)` or `Transaction(s)` remain in any of my files however.

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: restarted the the webbrick server

Comment: Can you run: rake routes?

Comment: rake routes also does not give any reference to transactions_helper.rb

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this same problem.  I know this is a very old question, but if this helps anyone out, I had to change the module name inside the helper as well as the name of the helper itself.

In this case that would mean the contents of `deeds_helper.rb` would be:

```
module DeedsHelper
  ...contents of helper...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the refactoring you probably did a search/replace but possibly left the original file behind.

You need to check out your app/helpers folder.

If you have a file called *transactions_helper.rb* make sure the the first line is

`module TransactionsHelper`

and not

`module DeedsHelper`